# Android calculator - plus button

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a plus button on my calculator. The first statement is to add a "+" sign when there is no input (calculation string variable holds all input from user). The second statement is to prevent the user from typing 2 "+" signs in a row by adding "".

It keeps giving me an error: `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0`.

```
btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override

    public void onClick(View view) {
        calculation = tvCalculation.getText().toString();

        Character lastChar = calculation.charAt(calculation.length());

        //App negeert deze statements
        if(calculation.length() >= 0) {
                tvCalculation.setText(calculation + "-");
        } else if (lastChar.toString().equals("+")) {
                tvCalculation.setText(calculation + "");
        }
    }
});
```

Someone told me it's because of the `toString()` at line 4.

Comment: ther error is for when the string is empty (length: 0). what do you think will happen if you try and find the last character of an empty string? also you should consider using char instead of Character and compare it against char literals, which use single instead of double quotes.

Comment: If I use char I can't use == or .equals() for some reason, so I have to keep Character. And when the string is empty, statement 1 is going to handle it.

Comment: that seems odd. `lastChar == '+'` should also work.

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Sorry my fault, I changed it to char now, it works. But I get the same error and honestly don't know what causing it.

Comment: Nvm I fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to read the last character of the 'calculation' string then you would need to do;

```
Character lastChar = calculation.charAt(calculation.length()-1);
```

Note the -1 after calculation.Length().